# Why is this badge that is awarded very fast, considered "rarest"?

Tags: discussion, support, badges

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: The *rarest* bronze badge you have is the autobiographer badge. It's technically true if you don't have any other badges, right?

Answer (score 1):

It is the rarest of the badges *that you have*.  Not the rarest badge *on the whole site*.  But since you only have one badge, it is also the commonest!

It would appear that the rarest [badges on the whole site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/badges) are

> Lifeboat Answer score of 20 or more to a question score of -3 or less that goes on to receive a score of 3 or more (None yet awarded)

Followed by:

> Publicist Share a link to a post later visited by 1000 unique IP addresses 1 awarded
>
> Legendary Earn 200 daily reputation 150 times 1 awarded

and

> Illuminator Edit and answer 500 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0) 1 awarded

Answer (score 0):

Tens of thousands of users have earned this badge. You just need to check the right links:

On meta, over 3000: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer
On the ELL main site, over 25000: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer

Answer (score -4):

It's considered the rarest because the majority of users here aren't inclined to share anything about themselves and just ask and answer questions in their field of interest.